# How to crash my Node app on purpose?

Tags: node.js

I've been working on a deployment work flow with Dokku and Docker and now I want to take care of continuity of my app (along the lines of Forever). To test it, I need a way to deliberately crash my app.

I created a new route '/crashme' with a function that is supposed to wreck my app.

Haven't found a way that worked locally with node/nodemon so far, I've tried:

- Division by zero
- Throw a new user exception
- Referencing a variable that doesn't exist

None of those things crash the app to a point where it needs to be restarted.

Just how can I bring it down?

Comment: You can try to kill it from the OS, e.g. with kill in Linux.

Comment: Push your app to production, that way it will definitely crash

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Three things come to my mind:

- You could just call [`process.exit`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code). This for sure brings your application to a state where it needs to be restarted.
- The other option might be to run an endless loop, something such as `while (true) {}`. This should make Node.js use 100% of your CPU, and hence the application should be restarted as well (although this, of course, means that you / someone has to watch your application).
- Create a module in C that crashes by e.g. trying to access a random place in memory. I have no such module at hand, but I'm pretty sure that it should be quite easy for someone with C skills to write such a module.

Comment: process.exit() is exactly what I was looking for. The loop is also a good idea, I don't know if Forever handles that.

Comment: Sure. It wasn't available when I wrote the comment. Cooldown is 5 or 10 minutes I think.

Comment: Can it be crashed such that it's not recoverable ? Like in unix/windows you eat up all space of system drive, so it doesn't have memory to boot even.

Answer (score 17):

I was attempting a similar thing with a /crash route in express, but just throwing an error from within the route handler was not enough to crash it.

process.exit would stop my app but forever would not restart it. (The forever logs just said something like process self terminated.)

What did work for me was inserting this into my `/crash` route:

```
setTimeout(function () {
      throw new Error('We crashed!!!!!');
}, 10);
```

Comment: as of today, I prefer this option. From ExpressJs [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html): "You must catch errors that occur in asynchronous code invoked by route handlers or middleware [...] If the try...catch block were omitted, Express would not catch the error since it is not part of the synchronous handler code"

Answer (score 10):

To add to Golo answer:

C module to crash by segmentation fault:

```
int main ()
{
    //Create a array of 1 char
    char a [1];
    //Create a index
    int i = 0;
    //Infinite loop to go around the compiler
    while(1)
    {
        //Write on case i of a, on the second iteration, it will write in unreserved memory => crash
        a[i] = 0;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    //Should not go there
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

And adding to [DrakaSAN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20842446/2700737)'s answer, an even simpler C module to crash:

```
int main()
{
    *(int*)(0) = 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Even shorter ones are available [on this page](http://llbit.se/?p=1744). If you don't want it to be too hard to read, you can probably go with

```
int main()
{
    int i=1/0;
}
```

Comment: can you please take care to explain each line? I'm not from C background, curious to know.

Comment: `main` is the function called when the program starts. We take the number 0 and cast it to a memory address `(int *)`, meaning that we now have a memory address pointing to 0, which is an invalid address for any program. The `int` means that this address is supposed to contain integers, but it could be any type here. Then the first `*` means that we access this (invalid!) address, and we write 0 (could be anything) to it. Writing at the memory address `0` causes a segmentation fault and crashes the program. The `return -1` is here to avoid compiler warnings, but should never be executed.

Comment: Awesomeness, Thanks a ton.

Comment: Can you please explain how you would invoke or execute this via node to cause the node process to crash?

Answer (score 0):

utilize "Maximum call stack" exception:

```
function recursive(){
    recursive();
}

recursive();
```

or make fatal exception inside v8 (default size of the nodejs app heap is 2GB):

```
function heapOverflow() {
    let s = [];
    while (true) {
        s.push("*".repeat(1*1024*1024));
    }
}

heapOverflow();
```