# How to crash a Node.js app programmatically (for test)

Tags: node.js

I want to test a Node.js app crash, need the process stop, not just throw some errors.

Is there a simple way to do it programmatically?

```
app.get('/crash', function() {
  //do something to crash it 
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to crash my Node app on purpose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840813/how-to-crash-my-node-app-on-purpose)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.get('/crash', function() {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    throw new Error;
  });
})
```

`process.nextTick` is required to make error asynchronous, otherwise Express will catch it.

Comment: Why do you need process.nextTick?

Comment: this is required to make error asynchronous, otherwise `express` will catch it

Answer (score 5):

```
process.exit(1)
```

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

```
process.kill(process.pid)
```

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal

Both will exit the process.