# How can I purposefully crash my node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, crash

How can I purposefully crash my node.js server? (I want to do this when certain fatal errors occur so they are brought to my attention immediately to be fixed)

I have seen this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840813/how-to-crash-my-node-app-on-purpose) but I do not want to use a C module or run an endless loop (since my app is running on a server where I pay for the amount of CPU time I use) which means it will be very costly and difficult to max out the CPU.

I have tried using process.exit and process.abort but that only closes the module it is called from.

For example my server is started by calling node main.js and it requires several custom modules I have written in other files. If process.exit or process.abort is called in one of those other files then it will close anything happening in those other files correctly but it will not close the entire node server and main.js.

Here is a simplified example of what is happening in code:

```
//crashServer.js
var exampleVar;

module.exports = function(){
    if (!exampleVar){
        var err = new Error("An error has occured");
        Error.captureStackTrace(err);
        //error logging code
        console.log("An error has occured and the server will now crash.");
        process.exit();
    }
};

//main.js
var crashServer = require("./crashServer.js");

crashServer();
while (true){
    console.log("Server still running");
}
```

If I run

```
node main.js
```

then it will print out server still running indefinitely.

If I remove the while true loop it will simply print out "An error has occured and the server will now crash." and then exit (since there is no more code to run). This proves the process.exit command is being run and yet the while (true) loop still runs.

Any other ways I can accomplish this?

Comment: Uhhh, `process.exit()` shuts down the current process, including ALL modules loaded by it.  Do you  have multiple processes running by any chance?  I use `process.exit()` to shutdown my node.js server and it works just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've edited my question with an example to illustrate what is happening for me

Comment: Infinite loops in Javascript are simply evil as they don't allow the event loop to do any of it's normal shut-down processing.  If you replace your `while(true)` loop with `setInterval(function() {console.log("server still running");}, 1000)`, your server should shut-down.

Comment: No need to remove your question.  You asked a question and it was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite loops in Javascript are simply evil as they don't allow the event loop to do any of it's normal shut-down processing, some of which is required in order to allow some Javascript events to be processed as part of the shutdown process.

If you replace this infinite loop:

```
while (true){
    console.log("Server still running");
}
```

with this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("server still running");
}, 1000);
```

Then your server should shut-down.